# saving simple XML files

Tags: c, xml, linux, fopen

I started using XML format to create file, for this purpose I use this code :

```
void xml_create_file()
{
    mxml_node_t *xml;
    mxml_node_t *data;
    FILE *f;

    xml = mxmlNewXML("1.0");
    data = mxmlNewElement(xml, "setting");
    data = mxmlNewElement(xml, "URL");
    data = mxmlNewText(data, 0, "http://192.168.55.55");

    f = fopen("/etc/share/backup.xml", "wb");
    if (f==NULL) {
        close(f);
        printf("backup could not be written.\n");
    }
    else {
        mxmlSaveFile(xml, f, MXML_NO_CALLBACK);
        close(f);
        mxmlDelete(data);
        mxmlDelete(xml);
        printf("backup Saved\n");
    }
}
```

when I check the file /etc/share/backup.xml, I found it empty !!!

how to resolve this problem ?

note : I use microxml lib

Comment: Why are you opening an XML file in binary mode?

Comment: what's the problem when using binary mode ?

Comment: What is this `close()` function? You should use `fclose` to close files opened with `fopen`.

Comment: Also, don't try to close the file if `fopen` returns NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
close(f)
```

should be

```
fclose(f)
```

(The compiler should have warned you about this.)